# Python Conditional Statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

Let's say I have 3 columns. They are 'Word', 'Word Count', and 'Positive'. The column 'Positive' is categorical by year. I need to find the most frequent words that are categorized by 'Positive'. When I use this code:

```py
df.sort_values(by=['Positive', 'Word Count', 'Word'], ascending=False, axis=0).head(5)[['Word', 'Word Count', 'Positive']]
```

it gives me this output:

```
Word            Word Count  Positive
BEST            2654899     2012
INNOVATIVENESS  541         2011
EFFECTIVE       16420419    2009
BENEFIT         9902500     2009
ABLE            4090099     2009
```

As you can see it takes in to account the years before the Word Count. If I switch them, then I just get the most frequent words overall. My solution to this is to subset the 'Positive' column, by only taking into account values >=0 and then sort by Word Count. My problem is being able to subset the Positive column without making it into a boolean, and then being able to put it into my function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't easily provide an example without an example of your data structure, but I think what you're looking for is a combination of [`pd.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group everything by year, and [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) to find the most frequent, or actually maybe [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) if you are trying to find the largest number in the `Word Count` column.
It might look something like:

```
df.groupby('Positive').max()
```